# evaluate difference between 2 dates to make a transition possible

Tags: jira

Is this possible to evaluate the duration between a specified date on a form of a workflow, and the system date ? that what I want to do, in order to show (if this possible too) a short message if 1 day occurs since the specified date above, forbidding the transition of the status Closed to Reopened...

Thanks a lot,

Christophe

Answer (score 0):

I think the Script Runner has a validator that does something like this but I can't find it. Then you could write a post function with the Script Runner. Otherwise it's back to creating a custom validator, as described in my book [Practical JIRA Plugins](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449308279) (O'Reilly)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ScriptRunner plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) in addition with the following script in the validator section for the **Reopened** transition:

```
Date now = new Date()
Date cfDate = new Date(cfValues['YourCustomField'].getTime())
new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()).compareTo(cfDate) <= 0
```

Replace `YourCustomField` with the name of your custom field. This will ensure that the transition will check whether the current date is beyond the date set in the custom field, and blocks it if it is.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you for your answer. 
It works to allow transition when dates are similar, but my purpose was modified by my responsible. He would like to allow the transition if dates are similar or if the duration between them is only 1 day or less.

Example :

System date is 09/07/2013 (Paris)

My date (dd/mm/yyyy format)                Transition allowed                    Why 
   07/07/2013                                                                           NO                                             my date is former to system date

08/07/2013                                                                            NO                                             my date is former to system date

09/07/2013                                                                                                  YES                                           my date and system date equals

10/07/2013                                                                                                  YES                                           only 1 day occur between 2 dates

11/07/2013                                                                                                 NO                                             2 days occur between 2 dates 



Here is the code I wrote in order to do that, but it does'nt work (maybe a Java syntax error?) :

Date now = new Date()
Date cfDate = new Date(cfValues['Date de clôture réelle de la demande'].getTime())
new Boolean(((now.getTime() - cfDate) / 86400000) <= 1) && (now.getTime() >= cfDate ))

Excuse me for my english. I'm french, and I try to improve my English.

Thanks a lot.